# Reading .bin file in python

Tags: python, signals, binaryfiles

I have a .bin file I acquired from accelerometer sensor. I want to read the data and plot it in python. I don't know how the data is arranged in the file. Basically I want to have the vector (vertical acceleration, forward acceleration, lateral acceleration) as an output.

```
data = open("left foot.BIN", "rb").read()
```

I tried opening and reading the file but I didn't understand the output

Comment: Are you expecting to read the `.bin` in a dataframe-like format?

Comment: Can you tell us about the type of the used accelerometer? Did you look into the datasheet fo the sensor to find out about the specific binary format the sensor uses? Which application is writing the *.bin file?

All of this information should enable you to correctly parse the file. When the data format specification is known, the parsing should be a piece of  .